# Unit testing error: "setUpClass error: NameError: global name 'doSomething()' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute *doSomething()* before every test I have. I just want to execute doSomething() one time. However, I am getting the next error message: **"setUpClass error: NameError: global name 'doSomething' is not defined"**

I have seen several examples of the implementation of setUpClass here in stackoverflow and my code is exactly as in those examples. I have been trying to change a lot of things in my code to make it works with no luck and I feel I am a little bit lost here.

Can anybody help me? Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
class Test_A(unittest.TestCase):
   def doSomething(self):
        print("class A")

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
        doSomething()

   def test_1(self):
        print("test 1")

   def test_2(self):
        print("test 2")
```

I am using *python 2.7*

Comment: `doSomething()` calls a *global name*, not a method on the class. You can't call `cls.doSomething()` because you defined `doSomething` as a regular method, not a class or static method.

Comment: What instance of `Test_A` do you want to execute the `doSomething` method of?

Comment: So, there is no any chance to call doSomething() from setUpClass() ?

Comment: Actually, I have several instances of Test_A. Since it is for Unit Testing I only run the test methods and this is made automatically (it is a little bit complex for me to explain, but Unit Testing works in this way).

Comment: I mean, how I can make setUpClass() call doSomething() ?

Comment: Martijn thank you very much for your answer, actually after several intents to understand what you were trying to mean I was able to put it practice your advice. Take care.

Comment: An instance method has to be called on a instance, something like `cls().doSomething()`. But I don't think this will get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the advice from Martijn:

```
class Test_A(unittest.TestCase):
   @classmethod
   def doSomething(self):
        print("class A")

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.doSomething()

Test_A.setUpClass()
```

Output:

```
class A
```

---

`cls` is the implicit first argument of the call.  Just as `self` is our convention for the object invoking an instance method, `cls` is used for the class calling the class method.

This is convention, not a language requirement.  You're free to use any valid identifier: `self` for everything, or `caller`, or even `xyzzy` or `plugh`.  The convention merely makes it easier for others to recognize the calling object.

Comment: Thanks very much! Actually (believe it or not) I was answering my own question when you posted yours. In the beginning, I didn't catch what Martijn was trying to say, but after a few experiments with my code, I was able to understand what he was trying to tell me.

doSomething() needed to be a class method to work. Thank you very much. Also thanks for clarifying my doubt with cls, I thought it was some language requirement.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Remember to upvote useful stuff as well.  I did so with Martijn's comment (after waiting to see whether he'd post it as an answer).

Comment: Sure! Actually I was looking some button to upvote his comment but I didn't find it, I suppose only answers and no comments can be upvoted. Really thank you very much as also thanks to Martijn, thanks to you people I am studying programming. Take care.

Comment: Ah ... you need 15 reputation for upvoting comments.

Comment: Here everything needs a lot of reputation points, is not fair haha.